# Sort a list of macros in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a rather large list of macros in my Personal.XLSB Workbook in Excel and I am wondering if there is a way to group them in some way so that when I search for a macro to run, I don't have to read through ~50 options. I understand that I can create the shortcut to run these macros, but it is not easy to store 50 shortcuts in the forefront of my mind. Is there a way to group similar macros in the Excel list. See the image below for the beginning of my list being referenced.

[image: Image of List of Macros]

I cannot remove them from the personal workbook either as the macros are required to be accessed from most files I work with.

Comment: They're sorted by name and you can't change that. You'd either have to rename them or use a different method of displaying/running them, such as Ribbon dropdowns, or a userform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workbooks saved in the `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` will be opened invisible when the Excel.Application opens.   By moving the macros into multiple workbooks and saving them to this location, you will in effect be "Grouping the Macros".

I would start by grouping the macros into their modules within the personal macro workbook.  Next I would create the destination workbooks, copy the modules over and optionally delete the original modules.  Next close Excel saving all the changes and then reopen the Application.

> ```
> Public Sub AddMacroWorkbook(WBName As String)
>     WBName = Replace(Workbooks(1).FullName, "PERSONAL", WBName)
>     Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=WBName, FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
>  End Sub
> ```

[image]

Comment: EXCELLENT! This is a perfect way to do this - I will use this answer

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Thanks for accepting my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way that you can group them, is by being careful with how you name them (which looks like you're doing already).

Might I suggest adding them to a custom Ribbon, instead of running them from the Macro Dialog?  That way you could organize them, and even show/hide certain buttons, when you need to, by what workbooks are open or worksheet is active.